# Странное поведение JSONB-поля у модели sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, python-2.x, sqlalchemy

Есть примерно такая моделька:

```
class User(UserMixin, Base):
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        _permissions = Column('permissions', JSONB)

    @property
    def permissions(self):
        permissions = UserType.One(UserType.id == self.type).permissions
        permissions.update(self._permissions or {})
        return permissions

    @permissions.setter
    def permissions(self, set_permissions):
        type_permissions = UserType.One(UserType.id == self.type).permissions
        for key, value in copy.deepcopy(set_permissions).iteritems():
            if type_permissions.get(key) == value:
                set_permissions.pop(key)
        self._permissions = set_permissions
```

Когда я пытаюсь получить `current_user._permissions` python почему-то всегда возвращает `{}`, вне зависимости от того, что конкретно лежит в БД в этом поле у current_user'a: `NULL` или дикт со значениями, типа такого: `{'perm1': 'val1', 'perm2': 'val2'}`.

Табличка в postgres создавалась примерно так:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, permissions JSONB);
```

Все перерыл, не могу понять, почему возвращается такое значение. Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался или знает, в чем дело?

Answer (score 1):

Таблицу создавал так же:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, permissions JSONB);
```

В таблице 2 записи:

```
1;{}
2;{"foo": "bar"}
```

```python
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.json import JSONB
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    _permissions = Column('permissions', JSONB)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/test')

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
session = Session(bind=engine)

for user in session.query(User).all():
    print(user._permissions)
```

Следующий код выводит:

```
{}
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

`JSONB` работает отлично.

Comment: А если добаыить еще одну запись, с NULL? Если я делаю прямой запрос к БД, то все ок. А вот если получаю данные из current_user'а, то не очень

Comment: С пустыми записями у меня вывод такой ``{}, {'foo': 'bar'}, None, None``. Я подозреваю что ваш курент юзер это не то что вы ожидаете. Попробуйте через``pdb`` посмотреть что это за объект.